# Why is Volumetric stress change in pressure not final pressure?

Tags: pressure, elasticity, stress-strain, viscosity, volume

While reading about volumetric stress, I found that volumetric stress on a body is equal to restoring force per unit area if force is normal to the surface and is proportional to the area.
At equilibrium,
So Volumetric stress should be equal to external force per unit area.
So if we add extra force and change the pressure at each point of object, the volumetric stress after achieving equilibrium should be the final external pressure but it is said to be change in the pressure.
How is it possible?

Comment: Can you give an example with a diagram>

Answer (score 1):

The [volumetric or dilatational stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor#Stress_deviator_tensor) can be defined as one-third the [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)) of the [stress tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor).

If a body is exposed to hydrostatic pressure $P$ alone, then the external forces act as normal to the surface, as you note, and the stress tensor consists of the [identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) multiplied by by $-P$; that is, $-P$ sits on the diagonal.

However, if one or more additional axial loads are applied, then they superpose on the diagonal and increase the trace and thus the dilatational stress (which tends to change an element's size), while generally introducing some [deviatoric stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor#Stress_deviator_tensor) (which tends to change an element's shape).

In this way, the volumetric stress differs from the externally applied pressure because the equitrixial stress arising from the pressure is augmented by additional stress as described above.

Does this get at what you're asking about?